# Android - Menu Item showing with and without icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a menu layout with an icon that must be shown if there is room (without text). I used it in two applications (with exactly the same place in the Action Bar). For one, the icon is shown alone, just like a want it to be, and for the other the title (text) is shown in the action overflow? How can it be?

Here is the main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/done"
        android:title="@string/done"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done"
        android:visible="false"/>
</menu>
```

(visibility gone is in purpose)

Is there something in the activity that can change INDIRECTLY the behavior of the action bar ?

**EDIT:**  Google System Image shows only the icon

Answer (score 0):

Seems that changing my Activity to extend Activity and not ActionBarActivity solved my problem.